# What is the exact meaning of self consistent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

I've heard the term *self consistent* being used when referring to differential equations, etc. but I have to admit that I'm unsure as to what is exactly meant by this. Is it simply that there is at least one solution that solves the equation?

For example, suppose I have a 2nd order differential equation of the form $$a(x)y''(x)+b(x)y'(x)+c(x)y(x)=f(x)$$ Would one say that this differential equation is self consistent if there is at least one solution $\tilde{y}(x)$ such that $$a(x)\tilde{y}''(x)+b(x)\tilde{y}'(x)+c(x)\tilde{y}(x)=f(x)$$ or does the term *self-consistent* mean something completely different?

Comment: Is there some additional physical context? For instance "self-consistent mean field theory" comes to mind here, but here the significance is more physical than mathematical.

Comment: @Ian           I've seen the term used in equations for physical theories, but also purely mathematically as well (even in the physical case there is no physical argument to invoke the term *self consistent*, at least in what I've been exposed to in the past).

Comment: I was under the impression that "self consistent" equations have more than one condition that they must satisfy. When the equation also satisfies all the conditions then it is "self consistent." Another instance where I have heard it used is when dealing with implicit equations, i.e. y = f'(x,y).